# For a Planar Graph, is it always possible to construct a set of cycle basis, with each and every edge Is shared by at most 2 cycle bases?

Tags: graph-theory

This is a slightly different question than the one asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/in-a-graph-is-it-always-possible-to-construct-a-set-of-cycle-basis-with-each-an).

I understand that for non-planar graph there are edges in the graph which has more than 2 cycles sharing on it. But for [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), can we prove that *it is always possible to find a complete set of cycle basis that each edge is shared by at most 2 cycles?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course true, with the basis cycles being boundaries of the bounded faces (after killing off all pairs {edge e, reverse of edge e}).

Are you looking for a rigorous proof? It should follow from the argument establishing the fact that there are such things as faces etc (see for example chapter 4 [here](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/basic.html)). How much of relevant topology are you willing to assume?

Comment: I don't know much about topology; is it possible to provide some outline of the proof?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Lane%27s_planarity_criterion I don't think there is a rigorous easy proof.

Comment: if the answer is yes to the question above, is there any method that can construct such a set of cycles for any planar graph?

Comment: I don't know. I was going to suggest you post it as new question, but I see you already did.